# Cannot find data type of value which Phalcon frame work is returning

Tags: php, sql, phalcon

I have the following code in my controller :

```
class skillsController extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Controller{

                public function indexAction(){
                    $this->view->disable();
                    $query = $this->modelsManager->createQuery("SELECT * FROM Skills");
                    $skills = $query->execute();
                    echo var_dump($skills);


                }

            }
```

I am trying to figure out the type of $skills varible , I have used var_dump but still no result , any other good recommendations.. possibly doing something wrong?

Edit 1 : Edited Code , I am trying to retrive information from table called skills through my skillsController

[Click Here for Error Message](http://pastebin.com/t2yFhneN)

Comment: Not sure what you want to accomplish and what you've tried so far. viewAllSkill is not a valid action, so where are you calling it?

Comment: sorry that i was not clear , also edited code , take a look now

Comment: Doesn't phalcon show you error message when you try to call such 'action'? It should be viewAllSkillsAction.

Comment: Ok, now it gets called, but it does not return/print/echo anything.

Comment: Because there is no return (print, echo). Just show how you print your debug info